# Using standard .NET Regex in Visual Studio's Find dialog

Tags: regex, visual-studio, finddialog

As most of you probably know, the regular expressions used in Visual Studio's Find dialog [are not the same as .NET Regex](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/07/the-visual-studio-ide-and-regular-expressions.html). This is a major PITA to me, and I often resort to external tools to search my code with regexes.

So, I have two questions:

- Why on earth did the VS team introduce yet another new, non-standard regex syntax? Couldn't they use the existing .NET Regex class? I can't think of any good reason for this...
- Is there a VS extension out there that would allow me to use the standard regex syntax in the Find dialog?

---

EDIT: I found two related suggestions on Connect:

- [Please consider using the same regex syntax for Find/Replace and the Regex class](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/573042/please-consider-using-the-same-regex-syntax-for-find-replace-and-the-regex-class)
- [Modify Visual Studio Find And Replace To Accept other Non MS Text Matching Engines](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/458656/modify-visual-studio-find-and-replace-to-accept-other-non-ms-text-matching-engines)

The second one is actually more interesting, since it would provide an extensible solution...

There are also a few VS2010 extensions (like [this one](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/a41d37d0-4b42-43fe-a9ec-4c2eb22bfaeb)) that allow searching with regexes, but none of them integrates into the standard Find dialog, and they don't have the "find in files" feature.

Comment: Why did the VS team introduce yet another regex syntax? I'm fairly certain the regex based Find & Replace *predates* .NET (I.e. Visual Studio 6), so it would have been fairly difficult to use it. And then you can't replace it due to backwards compatibility concerns...

Comment: VS regex is a defacto standard because it has been around for so long.  Just one among many.  Of course it makes sense to support another standard.  Or two, don't forget the C++ customers.  Ask at connect.microsoft.com.  I can't find any prior request, odd.

Comment: @Hans Passant, I actually found two requests for that issue, see my updated question for details.

Comment: For the first part of your question, see [this related question/answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181712/why-the-difference-between-net-regular-expressions-and-visual-studios-regular-e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 6 has Find & Replace [using Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264361%28v=VS.60%29.aspx). As such, it would be difficult for it to use a future product/framework to perform such a search

Comment: Yes, but I don't think the first .NET version of Visual Studio used much of the existing VS6 codebase... They created a new IDE specifically for .NET, so they could (should?) have used .NET regexes

Comment: @Thomas - They didn't rewrite VS 2002 from scratch - it relied on a lot of previous work. And even if they had re-written, there would have been backwards compatibility concerns (they still offer people VB6 era keyboard shortcuts when they first start VS2010...)

Comment: OK, but in that case, perhaps they should have provided both "old style regex" and ".NET regex" options...

Comment: @Thomas - oh, agreed on that. I, too, would like to use .NET regexes in such dialogs. But I can't work out a way to implement it myself in VS2010 (which is by far the most .NET extensible version so far).

Comment: I hoped it would be possible to "plug" a custom engine that would appear in the dropdown list with "Wildcards" and "Regular expressions", but it looks like this list is hard-coded... too bad