# Why does .NET and Visual Studio use different regex syntax?

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does Visual Studio use such a strange regex syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008010/why-does-visual-studio-use-such-a-strange-regex-syntax)

For example, Visual Studio uses `{ }` for capturing? Isn't that usually for quantifying? And it uses `( )` for quantifiers instead I think.  The escape characters use `:` instead `\` like `:d` instead of `\d` for digits.  But tab is still `\t`.

It uses `\1 \2 \3` for backreferences instead of `$1 $2 $3` like .NET.  It uses `@` instead of `*` for zero or more and `#` instead of `+` for one or more.  It confused the hell out of me when I decided to use the Visual Studio Find and Replace with regex.  Actually it's different from most standard regex syntax.

Comment: Looks like there's no real answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008010/why-does-visual-studio-use-such-a-strange-regex-syntax

Comment: Visual Studio 2011 will get the "normal" regex syntax. Finally. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Microsoft must have everything different than anyone else, it seems...

Comment: See also [Why the difference between .NET regular expressions and Visual Studio's regular expressions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181712/why-the-difference-between-net-regular-expressions-and-visual-studios-regular)

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/07/the-visual-studio-ide-and-regular-expressions.html Nobody knows why they use this strange regex.